# Converting a deque object into list

Tags: python, list, queue, deque

Currently, I fetch "list" data from my storage, "deque" it to work with that data.

After processing the fetched data, I have to put them back into the storage.
This won't be a problem as long as I am not forced to use Python's standard "list" object to save this data.

Storage Service: Google Appengine.

My work-around would be:

```py
dequeObj = deque(myData)
my_list = list()
for obj in dequeObj:
    my_list.append(obj)
```

but this seems not very optimal.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
>>> list(collections.deque((1, 2, 3)))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: nb. This works because a deque is iterable, and `list()` will make list from an iterable. (eg. `list(range(5))`)

Answer (score 0):

Since deques are iterables, you can also unpack it inside a list.

```py
dq = collections.deque([1, 2, 3])
lst = [*dq]
lst             # [1, 2, 3]
```

To create a new list object, you can even pack the deque into a variable as well.

```py
*lst, = dq
lst             # [1, 2, 3]
```